# Spark (scala) issue iterators

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm creating a function for mappartitions to calculate the maximum and minimum per partition. I created the function in pyspark but I'm not able to translate it into scala successfully. I apply this function two times and I want to run a zip in the result. This is the errot that I get:

result.zip(res)

type mismatch;

```
[error]  found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)]
[error]  required: scala.collection.GenIterable[?]
```

Here you have my function in python:

```
def minmaxInt(iterator):
    firsttime = 0
    min = 0
    max = 0
    for x in iterator:
    if(x!= '' and x!='NULL' and x is not None): 
        y=int(x)    
            if (firsttime == 0):
                    min = y;
                    max = y;
                    firsttime = 1
            else:
                    if y > max:
                        max = y
                    if y < min:
                        min = y
    return (min, max)
```

And here my code in Scala

```
def minmaxInt(iterator: Iterator[String]) : Iterator[(Int,Int)]={

    var firsttime = 0
    var min = 0
    var max = 0
    var res=List[(Int,Int)]()
    for( x <- iterator){
      if(x!= "" && x!= null){
    var y=x.toInt

        if(firsttime == 0){
            min = y
            max = y
            firsttime = 1}
        else{
            if (y > max){
                max = y}
            if (y < min){
                min = y}
        }
       }
     }

    res.::=(min,max)
    return res.iterator

}
```

Thank you in advance

Update:

Thanks for your quick response! The code is great, but still I have issues for the zip. I have twice your last code for rdd.mapPartitions and then I execute the zip:

```
 [error]  found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)]
[error]  required: scala.collection.GenIterable[?]
[error]             result.zip(res)
```

Comment: missing some context - the error seems to be in code that isn't presented here (there are no references to `RDD`s in the code you pasted)

Comment: This is what I'm doing, just taking a column from a csv and applying the minmax function.
`
val file=sc.textFile(path)
val split=file.map(x => x.split(","))
val col=split.map( x=> x(0))
var result=col.mapPartitions(minmaxInt)

...Later on, the same...

var res=col.mapPartitions(minmaxInt)
result.zip(res)
`

Comment: don't add code in comments - [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42067415/edit) the post to add the missing information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simpler (and more idiomatic) implementation of `minMaxInt`:

```
def minMaxInt(iterator: Iterator[String]) : Iterator[(Int,Int)]= {
  val tuple = iterator
    .filter(_ != null).filter(!_.isEmpty)
    .map(_.toInt).map(i => (i, i))
    .reduce[(Int, Int)] { case ((min, max), (i1, i2)) => (Math.min(min, i1), Math.max(max, i2)) }

  Seq(tuple).iterator
}
```

Which can be applied to an `RDD[String]` as follows:

```
// some sample data
def col = sc.parallelize(Seq("1", "4", "12", "3", "", null, "2"))

// "use twice" and zip
var result: RDD[(Int, Int)] = col.mapPartitions(minmaxInt)
var res: RDD[(Int, Int)] = col.mapPartitions(minmaxInt)

result.zip(res).foreach(println)
// prints:
// ((1,1),(1,1))
// ((2,2),(2,2))
// ((3,3),(3,3))
// ((4,12),(4,12))
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! As you can see in the updated question, still I have the issue. Any idea?

Comment: First - it's hard to follow with some of the code in the comment and some in the post body - please show the entire code in the post, so I can try it myself and find the issue. Second - this sounds like a separate issue, unrelated to this method, so not sure it even belongs in this post.

Comment: see updated answer - the code you pasted works, the issue is somewhere in code that you didn't share, so I can't help any further....